# Pandas group by is dropping the dimnension on which the grouping is done

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas dataframes. Each has a dimension and a metric. I need to aggregate the metric based on the dimension in each table and join them based on the dimension.
So:

```
A
dim1 met1
 a     100
 a     200
 b      50

B
    dim2 met2
     a     70
     a     20
     c      50
```

I use pandas.groupby() on each dataframe, but when I check the result of the groupby by doing .dtypes, I see that the dim1 dim2 is no longer present in the aggregated output.

So now, when I try to join based on dim1=dim2, I get message that dim1,dim2 does not exist.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Specify `as_index=False` when doing the groupby so that the grouper becomes a column in the output (the default behaviour is to have it a part of the index).

Comment: Thank you. Can you post as answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour with pandas groupby API is to have the grouper become an index in the output.

You can circumvent this by specifying `as_index=False` when grouping. For more information, see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby).

> `as_index` : `boolean`, default `True`
>
> For aggregated output, return object with group labels as the index.
>   Only relevant for `DataFrame` input. `as_index=False` is effectively
>   “SQL-style” grouped output

Not applicable when grouping Series.